How to generate a sample with a given spearman coefficient
In order to create a dataset to test a statistical calculation package, I want to be able to generate a sample that is correlated to a reference sample with a given searman coefficient.
I managed to do it for the Pearson coefficient, but the fact that Spearman works on the rank makes it quite tricky, to say the least!
As an example, with a code to generate spearman and pearson correlated samples:
from statistics import correlation

import numpy as np
from scipy import stats


def generate_pearson_correlated_to_sample(x, correlation):
    """
    Generate a variable with a specified Pearson correlation coefficient to a given sample.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : array-like
        The fixed first sample.
    correlation : float
        Desired Pearson correlation coefficient (-1 <= correlation <= 1).

    Returns
    -------
    array-like
        The generated sample y with specified Pearson correlation to x.
    """
    # standardize the pixel data
    x_std = (x - x.mean()) / x.std()

    # generate independent standard normal data
    z = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=x_std.shape)

    # Create correlated variable (standardized)
    y_std = correlation * x_std + np.sqrt(1 - correlation ** 2) * z

    # Scale to desired standard deviation and add mean
    mean = x.mean()
    std = x.std()
    y = y_std * std + mean


    return y


def generate_spearman_correlated_to_sample(x, correlation):
    """
    Generate a variable with a specified Spearman correlation coefficient to a given sample.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : array-like
        The fixed first sample.
    correlation : float
        Desired Spearman correlation coefficient (-1 <= correlation <= 1).

    Returns
    -------
    array-like
        The generated sample y with specified Spearman correlation to x.
    """


    n_samples = len(x)

    # Convert x to ranks (normalized between 0 and 1)
    x_ranks = stats.rankdata(x) / (n_samples + 1)

    # Convert ranks to normal distribution
    normal_x = stats.norm.ppf(x_ranks)

    # Generate correlated normal variable
    normal_y = correlation * normal_x + np.sqrt(1 - correlation ** 2) * np.random.normal(0, 1, n_samples)

    # Convert back to uniform distribution
    y_uniform = stats.norm.cdf(normal_y)

    # Convert uniform to same marginal distribution as x using empirical CDF
    x_sorted = np.sort(x)
    y = np.interp(y_uniform, np.linspace(0, 1, n_samples), x_sorted)

    return y

def verify_correlations(x, y):
    """
    Calculate both Spearman and Pearson correlations between two variables.

    Parameters:
    -----------
    x, y : array-like
        The two variables to check

    Returns:
    --------
    tuple
        (spearman_correlation, pearson_correlation)
    """
    spearman_corr = stats.spearmanr(x, y)[0]
    pearson_corr = stats.pearsonr(x, y)[0]
    return spearman_corr, pearson_corr




# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Set random seed for reproducibility
    np.random.seed(42)

    # Create different types of example data
    x_normal = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10000)  # Normal distribution
    x_exp = np.random.exponential(2, 10000)  # Exponential distribution
    x_bimodal = np.concatenate([np.random.normal(-2, 0.5, 5000),
                                np.random.normal(2, 0.5, 5000)])  # Bimodal distribution

    # Test with different distributions and correlations
    test_cases = [
        (x_normal, 0.7, "Normal Distribution"),
        (x_exp, 0.5, "Exponential Distribution"),
        (x_bimodal, 0.8, "Bimodal Distribution")
    ]

    # Run examples
    for x, target_corr, title in test_cases:
        print(f"\nTesting with {title}")
        print(f"Target correlation: {target_corr}")

        # Generate correlated sample
        y_spearman = generate_spearman_correlated_to_sample(x, correlation=target_corr)
        y_pearson = generate_pearson_correlated_to_sample(x, correlation=target_corr)

        # Calculate actual correlations
        spearman_corr, _= verify_correlations(x, y_spearman)
        _, pearson_corr = verify_correlations(x, y_pearson)
        print(f"Achieved Spearman correlation: {spearman_corr:.4f}")
        print(f"Achieved Pearson correlation: {pearson_corr:.4f}")




With the above code, the generated Pearson coefficient is of course not exactly equal to the targeted value due to the random nature of the code.
But I find that Spearman is systematically off by a much larger amount, which makes me suspecting a problem in my code.
I work in Python but any help is appreciated!

What have you tried? Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example that demonstrates your effort so far and indicate in what way it doesn't work

The optimisation for the Spearman correlation does not work, the optimization stops too early, before it reaches an acceptable solution. I think it would need other optimizer than the one provided in scipy.

One simple approach is to toss it into least-squares as a polishing method, with your initial approach as an estimate:
def generate_pearson_correlated_to_sample(
    x: np.ndarray,
    correlation: float,
) -> np.ndarray:
    xerror = x - x.mean()
    lhs = correlation*np.sqrt(xerror.dot(xerror))

    # standardize the pixel data
    mean = x.mean()
    std = x.std()
    x_std = (x - mean)/std

    # generate independent standard normal data
    z = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=x_std.shape)

    # Create correlated variable (standardized)
    y_std = correlation*x_std + np.sqrt(1 - correlation**2)*z

    # Scale to desired standard deviation and add mean
    y0 = y_std*std + mean

    def error_fun(y: np.ndarray) -> float:
        yerror = y - y.mean()
        corr_error = xerror.dot(yerror) - lhs*np.sqrt(yerror.dot(yerror))
        return corr_error

    result = least_squares(
        fun=error_fun, x0=y0,
        method='dogbox', jac='2-point', x_scale='jac', loss='linear')
    assert result.success
    return result.x

Shown only with Pearson; Spearman will be the same:
Testing with Normal Distribution
Target correlation: 0.7
Achieved Pearson correlation: 0.7000
Testing with Exponential Distribution
Target correlation: 0.5
Achieved Pearson correlation: 0.5000
Testing with Bimodal Distribution
Target correlation: 0.8
Achieved Pearson correlation: 0.8000


Thanks for the solution. I wanted to avoid this kind of approach and rely on a mathematically "pure" technique, so  I was wondering if my code for the spearman had a problem in it. But you're right, this method is working perfectly fine!
I was wondering if there was a reason why you don't use the scipy.stat.pearsonr function in the error function? Is it because it allows to factorize some calculation on x out of the function, hence optimizing the search for an optimum?

You can use pearsonr in the error function if you want, but yes, the approach shown extracts some of the x terms.

I finally managed to improve the above code for spearman correlation:
def generate_spearman_correlated_to_sample_bis(x, correlation):
    """
    Generate a variable with a specified Spearman correlation coefficient to a given sample.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : array-like
        The fixed first sample.
    correlation : float
        Desired Spearman correlation coefficient (-1 <= correlation <= 1).

    Returns
    -------
    array-like
        The generated sample y with specified Spearman correlation to x.
    """


    n_samples = len(x)

    # Convert x to ranks
    x_ranks = stats.rankdata(x)# / (n_samples + 1)

    x_std = (x_ranks-x_ranks.mean()) / x_ranks.std()

    # generate independent standard normal data
    z = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=x_std.shape)

    # Create correlated variable (standardized)
    y_std = correlation * x_std + np.sqrt(1 - correlation ** 2) * z

    # Rescale to obtain ranks (values between 1 and n_samples)
    y_ranks=1+ (n_samples-1)*(y_std-min(y_std))/(max(y_std)-min(y_std))

    # resample to respect the ranks
    x_sorted = np.sort(x)
    y = np.interp(y_ranks, np.arange(1, n_samples+1), x_sorted)

    return y

I removed the part where I project the ranks as a normal distribution. It is much more stable and give results much more acurate.
